# Are private tutors such as princeton review/kaplan subject to FERPA non-disclosure laws (United States)?

Tags: united-states, privacy, ferpa

Are private tutors such as princeton review/kaplan tutors subject to FERPA privacy (United States)?

Answer (score 1):

> Are private tutors such as princeton review/kaplan tutors subject to
> FERPA privacy (United States)?

When there is a direct relationship between the tutor and the student or the student's parents, **no**. But if the tutoring is school sponsored or as part of a federal government funded program, it could be.

> The Family Educational Rights and Privacy Act (FERPA) (20 U.S.C. §
> 1232g; 34 CFR Part 99) is a Federal law that protects the privacy of
> student education records. The law applies to all schools that receive
> funds under an applicable program of the U.S. Department of Education.

([U.S. Department of Education](https://www2.ed.gov/policy/gen/guid/fpco/ferpa/index.html)).

Note that I'm implicitly assuming that particular private tutoring firms such as Princeton Review/Kaplan do not receive funds under an applicable program of U.S. Department of Education unless some other entity is financing the tutoring, but I don't personally know whether any particular tutoring firm does or does not receive such funding.